# Very simple Slick query, get a single value

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I'm trying to introduce slick into my code to replace some existing `jdbc` code.

First of all I'd like to use a scala worksheet to run a really simple query, I want to pass in an integer id, and get back a string uuid. This is the simplest method in the whole codebase.

As I understand I need to make a connection to the database, setup an action, and then run the action. I have the following code:

```
val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:mysql://mysql-dev.${URL}/${DB}?autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8",
  driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", user = "${user}",password= "${pass}")

val getUUID = sql"""SELECT ${UUIDFIELD} from users u WHERE u.${IDFIELD} = ${Id}""".as[String]

val uuid:String = db.run(getUUID)
println(uuid)
```

I'm pretty sure I don't have the driver setup correctly in the `Database.forURL` call, but also the worksheet is complaining that the result of `db.run` is not a string. How do I get to the string UUID value?

Answer (score 2):

The `db.run` method returns a `Future[_]` type. You should use `Await` for getting result from it.

```
val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:mysql://mysql-dev.${URL}/${DB}?autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8",
  driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", user = "${user}",password= "${pass}")

val getUUID = sql"""SELECT ${UUIDFIELD} from users u WHERE u.${IDFIELD} = ${Id}""".as[String]

val uuidFuture:Future[String] = db.run(getUUID)

import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val uuid:String = Await.result(uuidFuture, Duration.Inf)
println(uuid)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm certainly further on, but my scala worksheet never gets to the `println`. From various google searches I think it's more of a problem with intelliJ than the code at this point